# Using mathematical typesetting packages with `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX`

Tags: math-mode, xetex, luatex, amsmath, unicode-math

Before an emerging of a Unicode-based  `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX` there was `pdfLaTeX` which directly could output to a `pdf`-format. For the convenience of a typeset of mathematics, the `amsmath` package was mainly used.

But after emerging of the Unicode-based engines, there also appear such package like `unicode-math` (also, `lualatex-math` for fixing some troubles). And now there are questions and problems of how or in what order to use these packages, because sometimes we encounter conflicts between them (mainly with `mathtools`), as evidenced by numerous questions here in tex.se.

Aslo, for example, if one use `lualatex`,  it is possible to use either `amsmath` or the  `unicode-math` package, or both (it's not uncommon).

Compare `Lualatex` + `amsmath`:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = utf8

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    I = \alpha\oint\limits_L f(x) dx, \quad \text{an Integral}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

OR `Lualatex` + `unicode-math`:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = utf8

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    I = \alpha\oint\limits_L f(x) dx, \quad \text{an Integral}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Summarizing, is is needed an brief instructions on how and what order you need to call mathematical packages for use with Unicode-based `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX` engines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David Carlisle said, `amsmath` works with all font packages.  It’s so ubiquitous, I’m not aware of any that are incompatible with it.  Many newer packages want to modify how `amsmath` works, and `amsmath` does not deign to change itself for them, so it is very rare for any package to need to be loaded before `amsmath`.  (Except document classes, which expect to come first.)  I often load `mathtools`, which loads `amsmath` and adds some fixes and extensions, rather than `amsmath`.

The `unicode-math` package loads `amsmath`, but if you want to load `amsmath` with any options, or to load `mathtools`, load them before `unicode-math`.

Other math symbol packages are compatible with `unicode-math`, in the sense that they don’t cause errors, but `unicode-math` will override other symbols with the same name at the end of the preamble.  Therefore, if you wanted to load `unicode-math` but change any individual symbol to its definition in some legacy package, you would need to copy and paste the relevant commands from the legacy package, wrapping the symbol definition in `\AtBeginDocument`.

If you want to use modern fonts for text and legacy (8-bit) fonts for math, load `fontspec`.  Loading `fontspec` will change your fonts for `\mathrm` and a few other things, and if you load `fontspec` after `amsmath`, it will also change the fonts for a few more like `\text` and log-like operators.  To turn this behavior off, give `fontspec` the option `no-math`. The `unicode-math` package loads `fontspec`, and can pass options to it.  It is possible to load `fontspec` explicitly, and then `unicode-math`, if you need to resolve a clash between packages that load `fontspec` with different options.

You can load `mathastext` after setting up your text font (which can be 8-bit or modern) and your legacy math fonts.  This will use the main font for letters in math mode, too.  You can also set up `unicode-math` to do that, but it takes more effort.

Finally, you can use `mathspec` in XeTeX to load modern text fonts as math alphabets, along with legacy math fonts.  This supports a few more use cases than `fontspec` and `mathastext`, such as using a modern font other than the main text font for math letters, or setting a sans-serif math alphabet.

Answer (score 8):

`unicode-math` and  and `amsmath` are not really related, the first is primarily about font setup and the latter is about defining macros for math layout structures and is more or less independent of the fonts used.

If typesetting mathematics using OpenType math fonts, it is recommended that you load both (load `amsmath` first). In fact the development version (v0.8p) loads `amsmath` automatically so just loading `unicode-math` will be enough in future.

For both lualatex and xelatex the default setup is to use OpenType fonts for text but classic 8bit tfm font metrics for type 1 fonts for math. For that setup it is recommended just to load `amsmath`.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger not the released version yet though, I'll add a note....

Comment: Is `amsmath` soon to be loaded automatically? Will that not break packages like `nath`?

Comment: @Gaussler is nath incompatible with amsmath? why?

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected. I seem to have gotten the wrong impression somehow. This is the second time in a row I get beaten by the English. `;-)`